# Segmentation fault in linked lists in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am trying to store variables into a linked list node.
The example I was given was

```
int main() {
   struct NODE * head = NULL;
   int x, newData;
   for(x=0; x<10; x++) head = addNode(head, newData); // newData scanf’d in loop, not shown.
      }
struct NODE* addNodes(struct NODE *ptr, int someData) {
   struct NODE *temp = (struct NODE *) malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
   if (temp == NULL) return NULL; 
   temp->data = someData;
   if (ptr == NULL) 
   temp->next = NULL;
   else
   temp->next = ptr; 
   return temp; 
   }
}
```

To modify it for my purposes, I would only take 2 integers as input, with a global head variable, i.e.

```
struct Set {
        int a;
        int b;
        struct Set *next;
};

struct Set *head = NULL;

int addSet(int aa, int bb){
        struct Set *ptr = head; //copy of head variable since I need to keep the head variable
        struct Set *temp = (struct Set*) malloc(sizeof(struct Set));
        if(temp == NULL) return -1;
              temp -> a = aa;
              temp -> b = bb;
        if(ptr == NULL){}
              temp -> next = NULL;
        } else {
                temp -> next = ptr;
        }
}
void main (){
    addSet(2,4);
}
        return 0;
}
```

However, when I run it, it gives me a segmentation fault. I know it's from the ptr variable (commented related lines out and it didn't crash), but I don't know what other way to get the pointer to head without copying it into another variable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) `int addSet(int aa, int bb)` never sets a return value.  2) `temp` in `addSet()` is not used in some way with `head, ptr`.

Comment: I'll try and find an answer soon, but there are some issues. `main`'s return type is void but you `return 0`. Also just some extra braces.

Comment: Your `head` is pointing to the `tail` actually, so that is why you cannot iterate over the linked list.

Comment: There are several problems with this code.  `addSet` never sets `head` to a new value, so `head` is the constant `NULL`.  It doesn't work.  Also, why the special case for `ptr == NULL` (in both vertions)?  In both cases it just sets `temp->next` to `ptr`.  Get rid of that useless check, and replace those 4 lines of code with one line:  `temp->next = ptr;`.

Comment: The second not even will compile. Check the curly brackes. The addSet function is wrapping the main function.